# "Sponsored Links" section is still shown with "Reduce Ads" privilege

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, privileges, advertising, sponsored-tags

Some tags have a couple of sponsored links. For example:

> [image]

I'd expect these ads not to be rendered when I have the ["Reduced Ads" privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads), unless I chose to disable the "reduced ads" setting.

However, even if I have *"**Do not** show me more advertisements."* enabled in my "Advertisements" settings, this block is still shown.

<sub>(And yes, these *are* ads. Otherwise, they wouldn't be linking through `https://engine.adzerk.net/`)</sub>

Comment: In regards to the downvotes: "Disagreeing" with a bug report is a little odd, so if this bug report is somehow _incorrect_, I'd like to know what's wrong with it.

Comment: You can make the argument that the links shouldn't be displayed, but it's hardly a *bug*. It's a grey area.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reduced ads !== no ads

As you can see from the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads) - it only talks about the two leaderboards on the question page.

> [image: exceprt from help center]

The screenshot on the page and further text also clearly tell you there are spaces for ads to continue and display - in the sidebar.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Oded. Apparently, I misunderstood the functionality of the privilege.